# jquery running to soon. working only in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I have set blog text in my page to opacity 0, so that it fades in to opacity 1 on page load with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').animate({opacity:1},700);
});
```

the text only fades in on chrome, in firefox the text is already set to opactiy 1 with no visible fade in effect. I have tried to put the code in the footer, but the text is still visible when the page loads.  I know for I.E I have to do it with a filter.

Comment: fadding is a pain in other browsers than webkit..

Comment: It works properly for me in FF 3.6.5 on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hacky but you can try setting a timeout after the page has loaded...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.entry').animate({opacity:1},700);
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks, any idea why it works in chrome and not firefox? i think it used to and then just stopped.

Comment: See the above answer, may well be more use to you. I was purely demonstrating a work around for using .animate() - ZeroPage's answer may well work better for you. ( just swap .animate({opacity:1},700); for .fadeIn(); )

Comment: mark the question which fixed your problem as solved by clicking the accept tick on the left hand side of the question please.

Answer (score 6):

If fading is your only requirement use the jQuery `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` functions as they are more cross-browser safe than animating the opacity property.

Comment: I do not want to hide the element though because i want to maintain the height of the div

Comment: could you wrap it in an outer div that keeps the height?

Comment: I think this is the best solution then, I had to do a lot of adjustments to various divs, to keep background images from looking wierd.

Comment: did some testing and it has to do with when i set the div initially to display none, to get the fadeIn effect

Answer (score 1):

The ready() event fires as soon as the DOM is constructed. Have you tried using the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event instead?